# Spring Batch doesn't propagate Errors

Tags: java, spring, out-of-memory, spring-batch

I'm facing some OutOfMemoryError while developing a Spring Batch job.
The most common way to debug this kind of error is to ask the JVM to generate a heap dump when it occurs. The issue here is that Spring Batch is catching all Throwable so they can be available after the job execution through `jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions()`. Hence no heap dump generated since the JVM is still running.

Is that a desired behaviour or should the `AbstractJob` class (in Spring Batch) catch only `Exception` instead of `Throwable` ?

My solution at the moment is to do something like this :

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    [...]
    Error error = (Error) jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().stream().filter(t -> t instanceof Error).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if(error != null)
        throw error;
}
```

I could live with that but I'm still not very fond of it because it means that my application is still running fo a short time after that OOME is thrown and that may incurs some bad behaviour in other threads.
Plus, if you don't face the problem before going to production and work around it you may live with an app that is still running after "recovering" from an Error of some kind, that si not something anyone would want in my opinion.

From the `AbstractJob` class :

```
@Override
public final void execute(JobExecution execution) {
    [...]
    try {
            [...]
    } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("Encountered fatal error executing job", t);
            execution.setExitStatus(getDefaultExitStatusForFailure(t, execution));
            execution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
            execution.addFailureException(t);
    }
```

Shall I create a pull request ? This is not a trivial change I guess...

EDIT : Created a Jira as requested : https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2800

Comment: `Hence no heap dump generated since the JVM is still running.` If the JVM is still running, I don't see how you get an OOM error.

Comment: The error is catched and logged as you can see in the code snippet from the AbstractJob class

Comment: Yeah but this won't prevent the JVM from crashing with an OOM anyway as soon as the catch bloc is executed. If you face an OOM error, I would recommend to first fix the OOM error before seeing why the framework catch all throwables. Probably your chunk size is not correctly sized, or you are loading too much (un-needed?) data, etc.

Comment: Well, unless I'm missing something big, of course this will prevent the JVM from crashing since the catched OOM is not propagated in the catch clause.
The main reason I want the JVM to crash is to generate that heap dump in order to fix the OOM. Hence my question...

Comment: You are right, sorry for mis-understanding your point. I don't have the whole history but there should be a good reason for that. Let me check internally and get back to you asap. In the meantime, can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I agree, there is probably a good reason. This behaviour is worth mentioning somewhere in the documentation though, and that's the point of this post.
I'm sorry, I resolved the OOM since and I can't find the stacktrace anymore, but it was a classic OOM due to a bad use of hibernate caches.

Comment: `This behaviour is worth mentioning somewhere in the documentation though` ok can you please open an issue on JIRA with a reference to this SO thread? If there is no good reason for that behaviour, we will see how to fix the issue. Otherwise we will update the documentation accordingly. Thank you upfront!

Comment: I created the Jira by the way @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!